# Do Two-handed Maces exist?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I was looking foward into creating a NPC which uses a two-handed mace but I couldn't find a good weapon fot it in Pathfinder. It should be a Greatmace or something similar. A weapon that looks like Leoric's Mace from Diablo III.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than creating an entirely new item, it can be perfectly valid to just "refluff" an existing item -- simply take an existing item, and give it a new description. If there's already a similar item but the name doesn't fit... simply change the name.

If you really want to make a new item, then simply compare other weapons to see how the stats might increase. shortsword to longsword to greatsword. Extrapolate that to how the stats might look for hammer to mace to the new Greatmace. Don't forget to consider which weapon proficiencies would apply, or perhaps it is so uncommon that it requires an exotic proficiency. (Or whatever special training entails in Pathfinder.)

Based on the various linked items in the other response, I would suggest that your proposed stats for the Greatmace (25gp, 1d12, 20/x2, 16lb) sounds pretty much in line. Less critical than the Earth Breaker, and heavier, which is inline with the cheaper price.

The last step to do is pass it by your DM for final approval. (Of course, if you happen to be the DM yourself, that makes this step that much easier!)

Comment: I really like the answer given here but disagree with your proposed stats for the great mace entirely. The maul, which exists in D&D 3.5 in CW pg. 154, is one-handed, 1d8/1d10 dmg, x3 crit, 20 lbs, 15 gp. A progression to two-handed using the PHB pg. 114 under Weapon Qualities would be greatmaul, 1d10/2d6 dmg, x3 crit, 40 lbs, your choice on price. Personally i don't think anyone would want a 40 lb weapon, which is why they don't have one listed. Just use the greataxe- get -0.5 avg dmg and save 28 lbs. Maybe ask your DM about giving it x4 crit or 2d6/2d8 dmg to make it more unique/worth it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple options.

The most accurate to Leoric's Mace would be the [Earth Breaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/earth-breaker).

There is also the [Great Club](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/club-great), the [Lucerne Hammer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/hammer-lucerne), and the similar [Bec de Corbin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/bec-de-corbin).

Comment: I've seen the Earth Breaker and the other versions as well. But would it be reasonable to create a weapon which is actually a Greatmace?
Martial:  Greatmace, 25 gp, (M) 1d12 20/x2, 16 lbs.

Comment: @Azrael Why? Just use the ones that already exist and describe them differently. You're just making work for yourself, not to mention you're just making a flat-out weaker version of the EarthBreaker and Greataxe.

Answer (score 3):

The Maul already exists and is just about exactly a two handed mace. Just flavor it differently.

Leoric's weapon would probably be a unique magical maul.